# Python - Get a substring of a Path

Tags: python, substring

I have a block that searches for a sub-string '.exe' in a given path. For instance, I have:

```
str1 = '.exe'
str2 = str(pathname)

while index < len(str2):
    index = str2.find(str1, index)
    if index == -1:
        break
    else:
        #extract process name going back from 'index' until the first 
        #backslash but 3 characters after 'index' (to include '.exe')
)
```

Essentially, all 'pathnames' will be of the form 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe, C:\WINDOWS\system32\sdra64.exe' with a potentially large number of process exe names I want to extract. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You just want to get the filenames right of a path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to separate the `dirPath` and `fileName` you can do that easily in python by using the `os.path` modules. No need to do slicing and substring operations.

```
import os
path = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\sdra64.exe"
dirPath, fileName = os.path.split(path)
print dirPath, fileName
>C:\WINDOWS\system32 sdra64.exe
```

If you just need the ending

```
print os.path.splitext(path)
('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\sdra64', '.exe')
```